# Setting Bin Path for Qt in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, qt

I just wanted to know what should I set the path in linux for bin path, and include path in eclipse in the linux os when adding a new Qt version? I have already downloaded and extracted the library, and tried to set the bin bath to tool, and the include path to include.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded via Yast or equivalent, then it will be your default system locations (/usr/bin, /usr/include), otherwise it will be wherever you downloaded it to.  It requires the bin path for moc, qmake, etc., and the includes for your own development.